# Django cannot show image

Tags: python, django

I use django in Ubuntu. I set static_url, static_root, media_url and media_root in settings.py like this code.

**settings.py**

```
DEBUG = False

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static','media')
```

In index.html I set image like this code.

**index.html**

```
<img class="rounded mx-auto d-block" width="25%" src="../media/images/iot_logo.png">
```

After that, I use command **django-admin collectstatic** and open website but it not show image. How to fix it?

Comment: Can you provide some sort of concrete error message?

Comment: It have no error but image not display

Comment: Try like this `{% static 'media/images/iot_logo.png' %}`

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in static tag

```
{% load static %}

<img class="rounded mx-auto d-block" width="25%" src="{% static 'media/images/iot_logo.png' %}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like path you given here in src is incorrect,

correct your path and image will be visible to you.